# Fetching users data from REST API

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

As I'm able to fetch the WooCommerce REST API JSON data loaded from the CSV file and save the same data to **wp_users** table through WooCommerce.

**Installed Plugins**
WooCommerce Version 3.3+ .
WordPress Version 4.9+.
WP REST API Controller Version 1.4.1.

I'm able to view data by calling WooCommerce class

```
try{
    $getcustomers = $woocommerce->get('customers');
    echo'<pre>'; print_r($getcustomers); echo'</pre>';
}catch (HttpClientException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); // Error message.
    $e->getRequest(); // Last request data.
    $e->getResponse(); // Last response data.
}
```

Not able to view the REST API data via POSTMAN from the GET request

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wc-api/v2/customers/
```

Results:

> {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key
>   parameter is missing"}]}

Here is the code

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require 'config.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;


$woocommerce = new Client(
    $store_url,  // Your store URL
    $client_key, // Your consumer key
    $client_secret, // Your consumer secret
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce API version
    ]
);


$raw_data = fopen("MOCK_DATA.csv","r");
$newCustomers = array();
while(!feof($raw_data)){
        $custInfo = fgetcsv($raw_data);
        $company = $custInfo[0];
        $fname = $custInfo[1];
        $lname = $custInfo[2];
        $email = $custInfo[3];
        $password = 'root';
        if($email == null){
            continue;
        }
        $new_customer = [
            'email' => $email,
            'first_name' => $fname,
            'last_name' => $lname,
            'username' => $email,
            'password' => $password,
            'billing' => [
                'first_name' => $fname,
                'last_name' => $lname,
                'company' => $company,
                'address_1' => '',
                'address_2' => '',
                'city' => '',
                'state' => '',
                'postcode' => '',
                'country' => '',
                'email' => $email,
                'phone' => ''   
            ],
            'shipping' => [
                'first_name' => $fname,
                'last_name' => $lname,
                'company' => $company,
                'address_1' => '',
                'address_2' => '',
                'city' => '',
                'state' => '',
                'postcode' => '',
                'country' => ''
            ]           
        ];
        array_push($newCustomers, $new_customer);       
}

foreach($newCustomers as $customer){
    $error_email ="";
    try{
        $error_email = $customer['email'];
        $results = $woocommerce->post('customers', $customer);
        //echo'<pre>'; print_r($results);
        echo 'Customer ' .$results->email.' was created' .nl2br("\n");
    }catch (HttpClientException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR ADDED: '.$error_email."\n";
        echo $e->getMessage(); // Error message.
        $e->getRequest(); // Last request data.
        $e->getResponse(); // Last response data.
    } 
}
```

**MOCK_DATA.csv**

```
1,Hugo,Pardey,hpardey0@gmail.com,12/20/2017
2,Felipe,Lorrimer,florrimer1@discuz.net,10/14/2017
3,Bran,Beel,bbeel2@studiopress.com,10/16/2017
```

What will be the required dependency to load, if there are any?
How do I GET the customers JSON data from POSTMAN?
And also facing difficulties in installing [kloon-WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library)

Comment: what is postman ? where do you use it in your code ?

Comment: A postman is a software used for interacting with HTTP APIs & viewing the data for clarity sake. It's an HTTP client tool for testing web services. @mmm

Comment: ok then I understand, you don't use this code with postman, you use directly the URL ? then you have to put the user key in the URL parameters or HTTP headers, read that https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication

Comment: without postman, is it not possible to [View List Of Customers](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v2.html#view-list-of-customers) via HTTP Request from a browser? since I have seen it, in an example [kloon-WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library) @mmm

Comment: you can make an HTTP GET request with a browser, it's explained in the link of my previous comment.